# Getting question mark instead of multiple while spaces while exporting to excel in apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am getting question mark symbol(?) instead of multiple white spaces in output excel. I am using apache poi 3.7. For single space it is working fine.

For example:-

if my input is "a  b" then generated output is "a? b".
Here a and b have two spaces in between.

Comment: Code please. Without code, how could we help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open your generated spreadsheet output in Microsoft Excel.

It is encoding issue. Sometimes it might happen that if your input contains multiple white spaces then Open office shows you as "?".

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet works just fine.
Can you compare with your own code and post some code sample if you still have the problem ?

```
    Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = book.createSheet();

    Row oRow = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell oCell = oRow.createCell(1);
    oCell.setCellValue("a  b");

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\test.xls");
    book.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. My code is same as you have mentioned. Output is perfect in Microsoft office. Only it is creating problem with Open Office. I think there might be some encoding issue while writing in open office and that is why it is showing question mark (?) instead of multiple space.

Comment: I just opened the file generated by my code in Open Office v3.4.1 and is shows the correct data, no question marks. Are you sure that your code outputs "spaces" and not some other "blank character" ?

Comment: Yes Eric. I have also tried doing the same. I took one string and printed in excel and it was showing fine in excel and open office. But my data comes from scanned PDF and I convert scanned PDF to readable one and then prints data to excel. I have also analyzed data in debug mode but it looks perfect at the time of inserting to excel.

Comment: First you should look at your data more precisely. For instance : loop on each character in your string and print the numeric value with something like "System.out.print((int)ch)". You will most probably discover that some spaces are not coded '32' (space) but maybe '160' (non breaking space, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). If that's the case you should replace those characters 160 by regular characters 32 before exporting.

Comment: Note that I just tested, and even non breaking spaces do export just fine to Excel and Open Office (Java string "a\u00A0 b")... Can you please paste here the result of this code on your 'str' string ? :   /*****/ System.out.print("Str=[");
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
   System.out.print(Integer.toHexString((int)str.charAt(i)) + "-");
  System.out.println("]"); /*****/

Comment: I am getting Str=[61-] a0-] 20-] 62-] as result.

Comment: Ok this is really strange. Using your exact string "\u0061\u00A0\u0020\u0062" the generated file is just file both in Excel 2010 and Open Office 3.4.1... I'm using POI v3.8. If you could post some code that demonstrate the problem that would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this solved my problem. As Eric pointed, one should find out first which character codes are creating trouble, in my particular case they where zeroes.

```
String s = getStringFromSource();
s = s.replace('\u0000', '\u0020'); // check values with dec to hexa first, u0020 means 32
cell.setValue(s);
```